# Cuda program crashes when using an if-conditional

Tags: if-statement, cuda

I got this very strange behavior that my cuda program crashes dependent on an if clause in my kernel. This piece of code works fine (same instructions, probably the compiler optimizes this?):

```
... 
if( value == 0 )
{
  result = make_float4(0,0,1,0.01);
}
else
{
  result = make_float4(0,0,1,0.01);
}
...
```

Changing it to this

```
... 
if( value == 0 )
{
  result = make_float4(0,0,1,0.01);
}
else
{
  result = make_float4(1,0,1,0.01);
}
...
```

makes my program crash with an unspecified launch failure when calling the next kernel. The problem really seems to be the conditional execution and not the value of *result*. Checking cudaGetLastError() does not return an error.

Anyone ever had a similar problem, or is there something like a thread divergence limit? Any idea how to debug this further?

Comment: Call `cudaGetLastError()` after a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` (or better use the code returned by `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` straight away). Unconditionally setting `result = make_float4(1,0,1,0.01);` does not lead to a launch failure?

Comment: Where and how are `color` and `result` defined ?

Comment: responding to "any idea how to debug this further" perhaps run the suspect kernel that you say is not crashing but is affecting the next kernel through cuda-memcheck.   In all probability, the little snippet of code you've provided here is not enough info to solve your problem.

Comment: tera: no, it doesn't. pQB: locally, just before the if-statement. Robert

Comment: cudaDeviceSychronize() is a good idea... I will try that...

Comment: Can you show a bit more code/context for this? It is very hard to say what is going wrong based on a couple of lines of code taken completely out of context with no information about types, definitons, etc. Help us help you.....

Comment: As suggested by tera, I added cudaDeviceSynchronize() and now I know that my kernel fails with an "unspecified launch failure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwser by myself with the help of the comments on my question: The error was way before in the code. The calcutation of *value* was the problem. There, I did an array out of bound access and it seems that the compiler optimizes this away when both the statements in the if-condition are the same.

This:

```
...
int value = stupidArray[wrongIndex];

if( value == 0 )
{
  result = make_float4(0,0,1,0.01);
}
else
{
  result = make_float4(0,0,1,0.01);
}
...
```

was optimized to this:

```
...
result = make_float4(0,0,1,0.01);
...
```

and so in this case no error was generated.